# Mock Middleware supplied to req in an Express Route using Jest

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jestjs

I have the following Express route:

```
app.route(`api/project`).post((req, res) => createProject(req, res))
```

In previous code, I had created middleware to attach Mongoose to the `req` object, so it can be called with `req.mongoose` inside of `createProject`.

The problem is that I don't know how to mock `req.mongoose` when used in Unit Tests.

I tried creating a Manual Mock of `createProject` (below) that called the real `createProject` with `req.mongoose` being set to the stub, but this caused a StackOverflow error.

```
// __mocks__/createProject.js

const { MongoMemoryServer } = require('mongodb-memory-server')
const realCreateProject = require('../createProject')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const createProject = async (req, res) => {
  const mongoServer = new MongoMemoryServer()
  const mongoUri = await mongoServer.getConnectionString()

  const options = { useNewUrlParser: true }

  await mongoose.connect(mongoUri, options, err => {
    if (err) console.error(`ERROR: beforeAll - ${err}`)
  })

  req.mongoose = mongoose

  realCreateProject(req, res)
}
```

So, how would you mock out the `req` object in a route before it gets passed down the line?

Comment: How are you calling the `createProject` controller in your test? Can you share with us the test and the `createProject` code?

Comment: With something like this maybe? https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-req

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I was making was that in `__mocks__/createProject.js`, I needed to be using `jest.requireActual()` to import the real `createProject.js` file, like so:

```
const realGetProjectDetails = jest.requireActual('../getProjectDetails')
```

This gets rid of the circular dependency issue and test works as expected.

Gotta love it when it's one little line of code that sends you chasing your tail for several hours.... :\